# How do I exit a node group?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

I selected a bunch of nodes that I wasn't using and that weren't connected and thought that I would see if I could group them.

Well, Blender let me group them alright, but now there is a green background over the rest of my nodes and I cannot select any of them anymore. I deleted the nodes in the group because I couldn't figure out how to "ungroup" them and undo would not undo the grouping operation.

Does anyone have any idea how I can get things back to normal or do I need to start all over again?

[image]

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can press <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> to switch in and out of a node group, or you can press the arrow button in the header to go to the parent node tree:

[image]

To ungroup nodes:

1. Go to the parent node tree
2. Select the group node
3. Press <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

Additional note to the top answer, the Tab key only works for one level deep of grouped nesting but the upward arrow works for groups nested several times (group inside a group inside a group).

If you're forgotten about tab (which I had) you can also right-click (assuming you have left-click select, in Blender 2.8 at least) and select "Edit Group" for the same function as pressing Tab to go "into" and "out" of a group.

Answer (score 3):

I found out that if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Tab</kbd>, you can back out of multiple nodes until you reach the first one (first parent).